# Halving problems with database

Tags: android, database

I am currently having a problem with my code. I'm working in android. This is one of my labs for school but i'm stuck as to why its not working. It has to do with a Database for a chat window I created in my last lab. I want to store all the chat into the database. I've always had difficulty with working with databases in programming. Ill post my two classes below. if anyone could help it would be very much appreciated.

```
public class ChatWindow extends Activity {

Button send;
ListView chat;
EditText message;
ArrayList<String> list;
String addText;
ChatAdapter messageAdapter;
public static final String ACTIVITY_NAME = "ChatWindow";
String returnedMessage;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_window);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_button);
    chat = (ListView) findViewById(listView);
    message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_text);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    messageAdapter = new ChatAdapter( this );
    chat.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
    ChatDatabaseHelper chatDH = new ChatDatabaseHelper(ChatWindow.this.getApplicationContext());
    final SQLiteDatabase myDatabase = chatDH.getWritableDatabase();



    Cursor cursor = myDatabase.query(false, MY_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    int numOfResults = cursor.getCount();
    int numOfColumns = cursor.getColumnCount();
    int getMessageIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_MESSAGE);
    int array[] = new int[] {R.id.message_text};
    SimpleCursorAdapter adptr = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_chat_window, cursor, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_MESSAGE}, array, 0 );



    chat.setAdapter(adptr);

    for(int i = 0; i < numOfResults; i++){
        returnedMessage = cursor.getString(getMessageIndex);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        returnedMessage = cursor.getString(getMessageIndex);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }


    cursor.close();


    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addText = message.getText().toString();
            list.add(addText);
            messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            message.setText("");
            ContentValues newValue = new ContentValues();
            newValue.put(KEY_MESSAGE, addText);
            myDatabase.insert(MY_TABLE, "", newValue);


        }
    });
}


private class ChatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public ChatAdapter(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, 0);
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return list.size();
    }

    public String getItem(int position){
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ChatWindow.this.getLayoutInflater();

        View result;

        if(position%2 == 0)
            result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_row_incoming, null);
        else
            result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_row_outgoing, null);

        TextView message = (TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        message.setText(   getItem(position)  );
        return result;


    }

}
}

public class ChatDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Messages.db";
private static final int VERSION_NUM = 1;
public static final String KEY_ID = "ID";
public static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "Message";
public static final String MY_TABLE = "MyTable";
public static final String [] columns = new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_MESSAGE};

public ChatDatabaseHelper(Context ctx) {
    super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION_NUM);
}


public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREAT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + MY_TABLE + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + KEY_MESSAGE + " TEXT " + ");";
    db.execSQL(CREAT_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + MY_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}







}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a question containing what you want to achieve and what is not working?

Comment: Hello, I am trying to save all the comments made in chat window to a database. Every time I press the the button to go into chat window it gives me a message saying that the app has stopped working.

Comment: Can you add the stack trace with the error message of your logcat to your question

Comment: I ran the debugger and its saying "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column id(code 1):, while compiling: select id, Message from MyTable"